# Model predicts only one class for all the test images

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras

0

I'm new to tensorflow (I using version 2.1.0) and have a problem. I want to teach my model to classify images. I have 4 classes. I use CNN and when training the model I have an accuracy of 25% (1/4 of the whole set) and I noticed that there is always class 1 predicted in the test class. I tried everything, zooming in and out, tried with color and black and white photos. My set has 3 400 32x32 photos for each class. Please help.

My code is below:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shutil
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras import losses

np.set_printoptions(precision=6, suppress=True)

image_size = 32

base_dir = 'resize\\train'
raw_no_of_files = {}
classes = ['car', 'motorcycle', 'truck', 'building']
for dir in classes:
    raw_no_of_files[dir] = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(base_dir, dir)))

print(raw_no_of_files.items())

data_dir = 'res'

if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    os.mkdir(data_dir)

train_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train')
valid_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'valid')
test_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'test')

train_car_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'car')
train_motorcycle_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'motorcycle')
train_truck_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'truck')
train_building_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'building')

valid_car_dir = os.path.join(valid_dir, 'car')
valid_motorcycle_dir = os.path.join(valid_dir, 'motorcycle')
valid_truck_dir = os.path.join(valid_dir, 'truck')
valid_building_dir = os.path.join(valid_dir, 'building')

test_car_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'car')
test_motorcycle_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'motorcycle')
test_truck_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'truck')
test_building_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'building')

for directory in (train_dir, valid_dir, test_dir):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

dirs = [train_car_dir, train_motorcycle_dir, train_truck_dir, train_building_dir,
        valid_car_dir, valid_motorcycle_dir, valid_truck_dir, valid_building_dir,
        test_car_dir, test_motorcycle_dir, test_truck_dir, test_building_dir]

for dir in dirs:
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.mkdir(dir)

car_fnames = os.listdir(os.path.join(base_dir, 'car'))
motorcycle_fnames = os.listdir(os.path.join(base_dir, 'motorcycle'))
truck_fnames = os.listdir(os.path.join(base_dir, 'truck'))
building_fnames = os.listdir(os.path.join(base_dir, 'building'))

size = min(len(car_fnames), len(motorcycle_fnames), len(truck_fnames), len(building_fnames))

train_size = int(np.floor(0.7 * size))
valid_size = int(np.floor(0.2 * size))
test_size = size - train_size - valid_size

train_idx = train_size
valid_idx = train_size + valid_size
test_idx = train_size + valid_size + test_size

for i, fname in enumerate(car_fnames):
    if i <= train_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'car', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(train_car_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    elif train_idx < i <= valid_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'car', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(valid_car_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    elif valid_idx < i < test_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'car', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(test_car_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

for i, fname in enumerate(motorcycle_fnames):
    if i <= train_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'motorcycle', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(train_motorcycle_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    elif train_idx < i <= valid_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'motorcycle', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(valid_motorcycle_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    elif valid_idx < i < test_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'motorcycle', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(test_motorcycle_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

for i, fname in enumerate(truck_fnames):
    if i <= train_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'truck', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(train_truck_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    elif train_idx < i <= valid_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'truck', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(valid_truck_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    elif valid_idx < i < test_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'truck', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(test_truck_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

for i, fname in enumerate(building_fnames):
    if i <= train_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'building', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(train_building_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    elif train_idx < i <= valid_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'building', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(valid_building_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
    elif valid_idx < i < test_idx:
        src = os.path.join(base_dir, 'building', fname)
        dst = os.path.join(test_building_dir, fname)
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

print('samochód - zbiór treningowy', len(os.listdir(train_car_dir)))
print('samochód - zbiór walidacyjny', len(os.listdir(valid_car_dir)))
print('samochód - zbiór testowy', len(os.listdir(test_car_dir)))

print('motocykl - zbiór treningowy', len(os.listdir(train_motorcycle_dir)))
print('motocykl - zbiór walidacyjny', len(os.listdir(valid_motorcycle_dir)))
print('motocykl - zbiór testowy', len(os.listdir(test_motorcycle_dir)))

print('tir - zbiór treningowy', len(os.listdir(train_truck_dir)))
print('tir - zbiór walidacyjny', len(os.listdir(valid_truck_dir)))
print('tir - zbiór testowy', len(os.listdir(test_truck_dir)))

print('budowlane - zbiór treningowy', len(os.listdir(train_building_dir)))
print('budowlane - zbiór walidacyjny', len(os.listdir(valid_building_dir)))
print('budowlane - zbiór testowy', len(os.listdir(test_building_dir)))


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, 
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_dir,
                                                   target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                                                   batch_size=32,
                                                   class_mode='categorical')

valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=valid_dir,
                                                   target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                                                   batch_size=32,
                                                   class_mode='categorical')



batch_size = 32
steps_per_epoch = train_size // batch_size
validation_steps = valid_size // batch_size


model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.summary()

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(4))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-5),
             loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['acc'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                             steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                             epochs=30,    # 100
                             validation_data=valid_generator,
                             validation_steps=validation_steps)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False
)


model.save('cars_' + str(size) + '.h5')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs = range(len(acc))

plt.plot(epochs, acc, label='Dokładność trenowania')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, label='Dokładność walidacji')
plt.xlabel('Epoka')
plt.ylabel('Dokładność')
plt.title('Dokładność trenowania i walidacji')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()

plt.plot(epochs, loss, label='Strata trenowania')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, label='Strata walidacji')
plt.title('Strata trenowania i walidacji')
plt.legend()

plt.show()

y_prob = model.predict_generator(test_generator, test_generator.samples)
print(type(y_prob))
print(y_prob)
#
#
y_pred = np.argmax(y_prob, axis=1)
print(type(y_pred))
print(y_pred)
#
predictions  = pd.DataFrame({'class': y_pred})
print(predictions)

y_true = test_generator.classes
print(y_true)

y_pred = predictions['class'].values
print(y_pred)

print(test_generator.class_indices)

classes = list(test_generator.class_indices.keys())
print(classes)

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
print(cm)
#
#
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm):
    cm = cm[::-1]
    cm = pd.DataFrame(cm, columns=classes, index=classes[::-1])

    fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z=cm.values, x=list(cm.columns), y=list(cm.index), colorscale='ice', showscale=True, reversescale=True)
    fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500, title='Confusion Matrix', font_size=16)
    fig.show()

import plotly.figure_factory as ff
plot_confusion_matrix(cm)
#
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=test_generator.class_indices.keys()))


errors = pd.DataFrame({'y_true': y_true, 'y_pred': y_pred}, index=test_generator.filenames)
print(errors)

errors['is_incorrect'] = (errors['y_true'] != errors['y_pred']) * 1
print(errors)

print(errors[errors['is_incorrect'] == 1].index)
```

Comment: Why does your output dense have 4 nodes `model.add(layers.Dense(4))`?

Comment: `model.add(layers.Dense(4), activation = 'softmax')` make this change in final layer.

Comment: I put 4 nodes to last dense because i have 4 classes

Comment: I add this activation and I still have 25% accuracy

Comment: Pass `scale=1/255.` argument to all the three `ImageDataGenerator` invocations, and see if it resolve the issue.

Comment: Now I have 58% acc and 70% val_acc so I think is progress. Thank you very much.